# Invalid Argument = The value '15' is not valid for 'StateImageIndex'

Tags: vb.net, indexing, imagelist

i don't understand this error , when i add files to my Listviwe at the same time a function extarct icon from the selected files and add the extarced icons to a  image list but when i selecte more then 15 files this erore message come up
"Invalid Argument = The value '15' is not valid for 'StateImageIndex'."

here is my code :

```
    Dim ofg As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim lvp As New ListViewItem

    ofg.Multiselect = True
    ofg.Filter = "All Files|*.*"

    If ofg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each File As String In ofg.FileNames

            Dim hInst As IntPtr = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE([Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0))
            Dim iIcon As Int32 = 0
            Dim hIcon As IntPtr

            hIcon = ExtractAssociatedIcon(hInst, File, iIcon)
            ico = Icon.FromHandle(hIcon)
            icondufile = ico.ToBitmap

            Img.Images.Add(icondufile)

            Dim C_File As New IO.FileInfo(File)

            Dim ItemFile As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(C_File.Name)
            lvp = Files_List.Items.Add(ItemFile)
            lvp.SubItems.Add(MD5Checksum(File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(hash_generator("sha1", File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(hash_generator("sha256", File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(GetCRC32(File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(hash_generator("sha384", File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(hash_generator("sha512", File))
            lvp.SubItems.Add(C_File.FullName)
            lvp.SubItems.Add(C_File.Extension)
            Dim Index As Integer

            lvp.StateImageIndex = lvp.Index 'The error comes from here

            ItemFile = Nothing

        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> Although the ImageList specified in the `StateImageList` property can contain any number of images, and the `StateImageIndex` property can be set to any value equal to or lower than 14, only the images at index positions 0 and 1 are displayed as state images.

So what are you trying to do with the `StateImageList` property?  Why are you setting it to a value greater than 14?

Comment: Because if i dont set the StateImageList index no state images will be shown :( HELP Plz !!

Comment: Do you have more than 14 state images?  According to the docs, only the first two (index 0 and 1) are used as state images.  So you should set `StateImageIndex` to either 0 or 1 depending on which one you want displayed.

Comment: The image list is empty , when i add files to the listviwe  a BMP images will be add to the imagelist  'Img.Images.Add(icondufile)' and then when i add more then 15 files an error message comes up , when i see how much images that i have in my imagelist a I find that i have like if i add 20 files i find 20 images in the image list , the question is how can i show more then 14 statimage a preview of what happens after the 15 files.... https://ibb.co/n1FKYv

Comment: The problem is solved i just remplaced StateImageIndex to ImageIndex